# Cosmonaut (Cosmos DB) - The input is not a valid Base-64 string

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I try to write generic cosmos Db classes which will be helpful when there are a lot of collections with the help of Cosmonaut, CosmosDb wrapper. Here is the example of Factory class

```
 public class CosmosDbClientFactory: ICosmosDbClientFactory
{
    private readonly string _databaseName;
    private readonly string _endpointUrl;
    private readonly string _masterKey;

    public CosmosDbClientFactory(string databaseName, string endpointUrl, string masterKey)
    {
        _databaseName = databaseName ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(databaseName));
        _endpointUrl = endpointUrl ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(endpointUrl));
        _masterKey = masterKey ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(masterKey));
    }

    public CosmosStoreSettings GetCosmosStoreSettings()
    {
        var cosmosStoreSettings = new CosmosStoreSettings(
            databaseName: _databaseName,
            endpointUrl: _endpointUrl,
            authKey: _masterKey );
        return cosmosStoreSettings;
    }
```

And I have my repository class which is

```
public abstract class CosmosDbRepository<T> where T: Entity
{
    private readonly ICosmosDbClientFactory _cosmosDbClientFactory;

    protected CosmosDbRepository(ICosmosDbClientFactory cosmosDbClientFactory)
    {
        _cosmosDbClientFactory = cosmosDbClientFactory;
    }

    public Task<string> AddAsync(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            entity.Id = GenerateId(entity);
            ICosmosStore<T> cosmosStore = new CosmosStore<T>(_cosmosDbClientFactory.GetCosmosStoreSettings());
            var response = cosmosStore.AddAsync(entity);
            return Task.FromResult(entity.Id);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Failed to save data into CosmosDb");
            throw;
        }
    } 
}
```

when I try to use that repository, I get the below error

> "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, 
>   more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters."

from line

```
 ICosmosStore<T> cosmosStore = new CosmosStore<T>(_cosmosDbClientFactory.GetCosmosStoreSettings());
```

I wonder if anyone can help me to find out the reason?

Comment: Can you verify your masterKey? Is it a string that contains two `==` at the end? Are you adding any extra characters, like `;` or any separators?

Comment: It looks like your master key is not properly formatted. As Matias said, make sure you are not copying any prefix or suffix characters by accident.

Comment: On a side note, you shouldn't be creating a new CosmosStore every time. You should register it as a singleton and inject it in your repository. Creating a new one every time might cause socket starvation.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta you are right, I was missing those "==". I still think we should get a better exception more specific.

Comment: @NickChapsas would you mind change those classes based on a better pattern as you suggested?

Comment: Cosmonaut docs have a section specific to that. You just register them with the dependency injection package and then you inject them in the class https://cosmonaut.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html There is also a sample app here: https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut/tree/develop/samples/Cosmonaut.NetCore2WebApi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, the source of the issue is that the `_masterKey` provided was not a valid Base 64 string nor a valid Cosmos DB key.